# UISplitViewController (Swift): Show / hide master view controller on iPhone programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I am currently trying to port our existing app to Swift. I used a lot of 3rd party libraries in the "old" app, but I want to avoid that in the new implementation, because it gave me some heavy compatibility issues with newer iOS versions.

So here is my situation: I previously used a MMDrawerController (https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) to create a main menu, that can be swiped in from the left at any time (regardless which ViewController is shown in center as main view). Now I am trying to achieve the same functionality with UISplitViewController in my Swift app.

Everything works fine on the iPad. 
* Landscape: MasterViewController (main menu) is visible all the time. That's ok because we have enough space
* Portrait: MasterViewController can be swiped in from the left (or can be toggled via displayModeItem())

But I am facing issues on iPhone and I am not sure if I could solve them anyhow. Is there a way to show the MasterViewController (via UIBarButtonItem) from ANY ViewController that is in the detail navigation stack? I know it's impossible to show it as an overlay like on iPad, but I need a functionality to toggle the current DetailViewController with the MasterViewController (and vice versa).

Any ideas are appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: You should post some code, too much abstract talk. In a 'general sense' though, you need 2 UIViewControllers and you need to move their frames accordingly

Comment: SplitViewController in Iphone doesn't show like normal sideMenu irrespective of ObjC/Swift language.